# Get list of APIs using 3 table joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables from which I would like to get some data:

Main table:

```
    create table if not exists exchange
    (
        id bigint,
        name varchar(255),
    );
    
    INSERT INTO exchange (id, name) 
    VALUES (1, 'PARIS');
```

Second table:

```
    create table exchange_api
    (
        id                           bigint,
        api_name                     varchar(255),
        exchange_id                  bigint
    );

INSERT INTO exchange_api (id, api_name, exchange_id)
   VALUES (8, 'PARIS-API', 5);
```

Third table:

```
create table instrument
(
    id               bigint,
    symbol           varchar(255),
    exchange_api_id  bigint
);

INSERT INTO instrument (id, symbol, exchange_api_id)
VALUES (47, 'PARIS-ARD', 8);
INSERT INTO instrument (id, symbol, exchange_api_id)
VALUES (48, 'PARIS-SRD', 8);
```

I need to map the the tables following way:

First table `exchange` I want to send param `PARIS`

and as a result I want to get this result:

```
PARIS-ARD
PARIS-SRD
```

How I can get this data using `JOIN`?

Comment: What are your tries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
instrument.symbol           
FROM exchange
JOIN exchange_api
ON exchange.id = exchange_api.exchange_id  
JOIN instrument
ON exchange_api.id = instrument.exchange_api_id  
WHERE exchange.name = 'PARIS'
```

And with ALIAS:

```
SELECT 
inst.symbol as I         
FROM exchange AS e
JOIN exchange_api AS ea
ON e.id = ea.exchange_id  
JOIN instrument inst
ON ea.id = inst.exchange_api_id  
WHERE e.name = 'PARIS'
```

Comment: Can you show me how I can use table short name? Maybe instrument.symbol I?

Comment: @user1285928 please review my update, I don't know if I could understand you and that is what you want. Please let me know and I'll glad to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select I.symbol from instrument I 
inner join exchange_api API 
On I.exchange_api_id API.id
Inner JOIN exchange E
ON API.exchange_id = E.id
where E.name = 'PARIS'
```

If you want pass Pass **'PARIS'** as value then it will return

```
PARIS-ARD
PARIS-SRD
```

as output

Comment: Can you show me how I can use table short name?